# How do I sort a dictionary in decreasing order based on values of the list as its value?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary as below:

```
{'Muguruza': [0, 0, 1, 12, 2, 15], 'Williams': [0, 1, 2, 15, 1, 12], 'Murray': [2, 2, 16, 143, 13, 142], 'Djokovic': [3, 1, 13, 142, 16, 143]}
```

I want to sort it in decreasing order based on the values in the corresponding list.

I have to print out to the screen a summary in decreasing order of ranking, where the ranking is according to the criteria 1-6(as given in the list) in that order (compare item 1, if equal compare item 2, if equal compare item 3 etc, noting that for items 5 and 6 the comparison is reversed).

My output should be as below:

```
Djokovic 3 1 13 142 16 143
Murray 2 2 16 143 13 142
Williams 0 1 2 15 1 12
Muguruza 0 0 1 12 2 15
```

Here Williams and Murray had same value for element at index 0 of the list so they are compared on the basis of value at the next index in the list.

How can I do this in Python?

Comment: This seems to be a homework problem. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @GáborErdős My actual problem statement was to read a file and come out with a sorted output as given in the question description. The file was in the form as below: Djokovic:Murray:2-6,6-7,7-6,6-3,6-1
Murray:Djokovic:6-3,4-6,6-4,6-3
Djokovic:Murray:6-0,7-6,6-7,6-3
Murray:Djokovic:6-4,6-4
Djokovic:Murray:2-6,6-2,6-0
Murray:Djokovic:6-3,4-6,6-3,6-4
Djokovic:Murray:7-6,4-6,7-6,2-6,6-2
Murray:Djokovic:7-5,7-5
Williams:Muguruza:3-6,6-3,6-3. I have written code to successfully read the file and update the data based on conditions given in Pset in the dictionary which I have mentioned.

Comment: So, you want your output to be a list of the keys, ordered according to what their values were? Because you can't sort a dictionary.

Comment: please copy your comment code into your question and format it

Comment: @KyleBaker If it would have been a simple dictionary with key and value then I would have been able to sort it but here the value is in form of a list and also the various elements in the list for different keys can be same in which case I would need to look for the next element in the list. This is where I am facing the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just compare python list with `>` `<` `=`. Simple as that. It will do the exact same thing as you want. 
Also `operator` is a great way to sort dicts based on values

```
dict = {'Muguruza': [0, 0, 1, 12, 2, 15], 'Williams': [0, 1, 2, 15, 1, 12], 'Murray': [2, 2, 16, 143, 13, 142], 'Djokovic': [3, 1, 13, 142, 16, 143]}
import operator
print(sorted(dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)))

for i in sorted_list:
    print(i[0], " ".join([str(j) for j in i[1]]))
```

Returns

```
Williams 0 1 2 15 1 12
Murray 2 2 16 143 13 142
Djokovic 3 1 13 142 16 143
Muguruza 9 0 1 12 2 15
```

Comment: to match the order he wanted you should add `, reverse=True` to `sorted` function

Comment: Yeah i missed that part, but as i see only element 5 and 6 are reversed. In that case i would just preprocess the lists and swap the values. I guess its easier that way.

Comment: @Does using itemgetter(1) takes care of a situation where there are multiple same values for 2 keys. For example if {key1: [1,2,3,15], key2:[1,2,3,4]}
So will using this put the key2 ahead of key1 in case of ascending sort?

Comment: @Varun Yes it does! Try it yourself with the example you provided

Comment: @Varun You are welcome. Dont forget to mark the answer as correct please

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible answer:

```
import operator

data = {
    'Muguruza': [0, 0, 1, 12, 2, 15],
    'Williams': [0, 1, 2, 15, 1, 12],
    'Murray': [2, 2, 16, 143, 13, 142],
    'Djokovic': [3, 1, 13, 142, 16, 143]
}

output = reversed(sorted(data.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)))
print("\n".join([(i[0] + " ".join([str(j) for j in i[1]])) for i in output]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
d={'Muguruza': [0, 0, 1, 12, 2, 15], 'Williams': [0, 1, 2, 15, 1, 12], 'Murray': [2, 2, 16, 143, 13, 142], 'Djokovic': [3, 1, 13, 142, 16, 143]}
for v,k in sorted((v,k) for k,v in d.items()):
    print(k,"\t".join(v))
```